# iPhone 5 retina display aspect ratio from AVFoundation

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avcapturesession, aspect-ratio

AVFoundation provides different image aspect ratios that one can use when displaying video.

For example:

```
- NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset320x240;
- NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288;
- NSString *const AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

On the iPhone4 and iPad, these resolutions are designed to be full-screen. But on an iPhone 5 with a retina display, the iPhone display is taller.

How is one supposed to handle displaying the video feed coming out of AvFoundation? Any options other than having to choose a larger aspect ratio and crop it, scale the video (messing up its aspect ratio), or leave some empty screen real estate in our app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080` preset on iPhone 5. See the [AVCaptureSession Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080) **for iOS**.

EDIT:

`AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame960x540` preset has the same ratio as `AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080`. This should be the best choice if you want to improve performance and keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: What we're using the camera feed is pretty cpu intensive, and our performance drops down exponentially when using larger image sizes. What we really want is something with the iphone 5 aspect ratio, but not at full resolution.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Now hopefully that lower resolution will be performant enough for us.

Comment: Nope, the resolution is still too high. Oh well. Gonna have to figure something else out.